# (Have a problem) AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'

Tags: telegram-bot

Have a problem with telegram bot for forwarding messages from people to my channel

from asyncio import Queue
from telegram import Bot, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext

my_queue = Queue()

Initialize the bot with your API token
bot = Bot(token="хххх")

Define your target channel's chat ID (as an integer)
target_channel_id = "хххх"

Define a function to forward messages
def forward_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
message = update.message
Forward the message to your target channel
bot.send_message(chat_id=target_channel_id, text=message.text)
Put the message into the queue
my_queue.put(message.text)

def main():
Create an Updater without the use_context argument
updater = Updater(bot=bot, update_queue=my_queue)

Get the dispatcher to register handlers
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

Set up the message handler to trigger the forward_message function
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & Filters.chat(chat_id=target_channel_id), forward_message))
Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

- `
- `